# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The operation has timed out

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am receiving this error when I try to debug the application connecting through VPN.Any suggestions please

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304475/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-the-operation-timed-out/52487599#52487599

Answer (score 17):

To solve this I did reset of IIS as per below command:

```
iisreset /stop
iisreset /start
```

If not simply rebooting the system will also work.

Comment: Make sure you run the commands in admin and that you have permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Increase timeout of the Application Pool of your website on IIS from 90 to 120 (or even more), then restart IIS

[image: Increase timeout of the Application Pool of your website on IIS from 90 to 120 or more then restart IIS]

Make sure the pool for your website worked again after you restarted IIS

Answer (score 3):

In my case I end the iis worker procees. Then in visual execute the proyect again and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and restart IIS works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by doing a DNS flush: `ipconfig/flushdns` in command prompt.

You can also reboot your computer. Turning it off and back on again is usually the quick fix to all IT problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had a browser window already open and I was running the application. When I closed the all the browsers and started running the application it worked. This was the case for both Edge and Chrome.